# PHP Top rated stories

Tags: php, vote-up-buttons

I have 2 tables:

**stories**
ID (int), CONTENT (text)

**votes**
ID (int), TYPE (int, 1 or 0), ID_STORY (int)

How can I get the query to return the first top 10 stories ordered by votes (=1) desc.? I want to be able to print the top 10 stories content.

I've tried a lot of solution offered here for similar issues, but I couldn't manage to get it right...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *, count(votes) AS vcount
  FROM stories s, votes v
 WHERE s.id=v.id_story
   AND v.type=1
 GROUP BY v.id_story
 ORDER BY vcount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    storyid,content 
FROM 
    stories 
WHERE 
    storyid IN (
        SELECT 
            storyid,count(votes) AS count 
        FROM 
            stories LEFT JOIN votes ON stories.storyid=votes.storyid 
        WHERE 
            type=1 
            GROUP BY votes.storyid 
            ORDER BY count DESC
)
```